# How to avoid a query string parameter being remembered?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, query-string, tempdata

I'm developing a messaging system on a website.

When user sends a message, she is redirected to `inbox?status=sent` which displays a neat status *Message sent*.

However, if she then goes on to see any of the inbox messages and clicks **Back**, she is brought to this statusful page again, whereas I don't want to display it anymore.

What is the standard way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `TempData`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendMessage()
{
    // TODO: send the message

    TempData["status"] = "sent";
    return RedirectToAction("Result");
}
```

and in the Result view you could show the message by fetching it from TempData:

```
<div>@TempData["status"]</div>
```